# JQuery call not hitting server on $.post

Tags: jquery, python, django, post

I am trying to make a simple POST request to a server using Django. I can make the post call using another api client just to test it, but when using jquery it never return anything or shows the alert from the callback function. Below are my jquery and django code. I've replaced the api call but I know that it is correct.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#signInSubmit").click(function(){
    alert("Posting email: "+$("#email").val()+" guests: "+$("#guests").val());
    $.post("apicall",
    {
      'email':$("#email").val(),
      'guests':$("#guests").val(),
      'event':"1"
    },
    function(data,status) {
               alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
});
```

And this is the django view getting hit:

```
@csrf_exempt
def participant_info(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        participant_email = request.GET.get('email')
        participant = Participant.objects.get(email = participant_email)

        #serialized_obj = serializers.serialize('json', [ participant, ])

        response = HttpResponse()
        response.content = serialized_obj = serializers.serialize('json', [ participant, ])
        response['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        return response

        #return HttpResponse(response, mimetype="application/json")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        participant_email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        numguests = request.POST.get('guests', '')
        eventid = request.POST.get('event', '')

        participantkey = Participant.objects.get(email = participant_email)
        eventkey = Event.objects.get(id=eventid)
        per = Participant_Event_Record(guests = numguests, event = eventkey, participant = participantkey)
        per.save()

        response = HttpResponse()
        response.content = serialized_obj = serializers.serialize('json', [ per, ])
        response['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        return response
```

Comment: Have you watched the request / response cycle using some thing like Firebug to see what, if any, errors are generated?

Comment: Does GET work? I see in your code it handles both GET and POST requests?

Comment: like Jay said, you should check the Network tab in Chrome to see what's going on when that POST is hit

Comment: If you are using IE (I think 8+), make sure you set `cache: false` in your ajax requests.

Comment: Yes, GET works perfectly, and POST works when I use Postman, a RESTful interface for Chrome I use for testing. I will check the network tab and see what is happening.

Comment: It seems as though it is just doing another GET on the page when I hit the post... but why? After hitting the button, the URL adds the /?email=formvalue&guests=formvalue (in this case formvalue being whatever I typed in)

Answer (score 1):

Could be a couple things going on I think:

1. Specify the content type in the jQuery call, make sure it says 'appliciation/json' (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) since you're serializing assuming it's JSON but it defaults to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.
2. Your POST url expects a / at the end of its URL, and you're posting to an endpoint without a /, which makes Django issue a redirect to the / URL. You can disable that by setting the APPEND_SLASH setting (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#append-slash), but really it's best to always call all endpoints with '/' at the end, so I'd say instead of posting with $.post("apicall", ...), try $.post("apicall/", ...) and see if that helps.

Otherwise, can you post the error that you get when you do try? both from the Django console and the Javascript console in Chrome?

Comment: I am definitely new to this. It turns out that above in the HTML that I was not looking through was a form wrapping class, so yes, it was not only going to do it wrong, but the call really was not being made correctly at all. It hit the function but the post method just posted back to the page I think.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was wrapped in a form within the body of the HTML that I had not noticed. After removing the form wrapper it worked perfectly.